# Xaml - Unable to get item Name in class file (inside listView)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, xamarin

I'm making an XAML app and i'm having some issues binding my xaml file with its class .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
x:Class="App.TestXaml"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <ContentPage.Content>

 <ListView x:Name="ListTest">

      <Label FontSize="12" x:Name="test1"/>


        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                 <DataTemplate> 

                    <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Label FontSize="14" x:Name="test2"/>

                            </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>

          </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

in my cs file testXaml.cs thats linked to this xaml :

```
test1.FontSize = 20 ;
```

// Works - it detects the test1 variable for that label.

In my listview however , when i try to access the label named test2 , it does not detect it in my cs file

```
test2.FontSize = 24 ;
```

// The class does not detect test2 (The name test2 does not exist in the current context)

Any idea how to fix this or set up a value for the list items from my cs file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the controls that are inside the itemtemplate by their name.

You have 2 options

1. Use a property in the binded item for the font size and bind it to the fontsize of the control. I think this is more clean solution.
2. Use triggers as described by @ed

But i would definetely go with Mvvm

Answer (score 0):

If you need more programmatic decision here is another option. 
Derive MyViewCell from ViewCell and your xml will look the same except MyViewCell and I added binding to show something. You will need to add local code reference to use MyViewCell in xaml

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonRendererDemo;assembly=ButtonRendererDemo"
             x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.ListCellAccessPage">  
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="ListTest" HasUnevenRows="true">
      <Label FontSize="12" x:Name="test1"/>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <local:MyViewCell>
            <StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label FontSize="14" x:Name="test2" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </local:MyViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Now here is the code behind

```
namespace ButtonRendererDemo
{
    public partial class ListCellAccessPage : ContentPage
    {
        MyListItem[] listItems = new MyListItem[]
        {
            new MyListItem { Name= "1" },
            new MyListItem{Name= "2" },
            new MyListItem{Name= "3" },
            new MyListItem{Name= "4" }
        };

        public ListCellAccessPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            test1.Text = "List";
            ListTest.ItemsSource = listItems;
        }

    }

    class MyListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class MyViewCell : ViewCell
    {

        protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
        {
            base.OnChildAdded(child);
            var label = child.FindByName<Label>("test2");
            if (label != null)
            {
                label.PropertyChanged -= Label_PropertyChanged1;//unsubscribe in case of cell reuse
                label.PropertyChanged += Label_PropertyChanged1;
            }

        private void Label_PropertyChanged1(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var label = sender as Label;
            if ((label != null) && (e.PropertyName == "Text"))
            {
                if (label.Text == "3")
                    label.FontSize = 48;
                else
                    label.FontSize = 14;//in case of cell reuse
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

So, it examines the content of your cell and if it is confirms certain condition (in this case name is 3) it sets the font. Here is the screenshot

[image]